# try to get all if individual_sex is match then return both product_id

Tags: php, xml, xpath

This is my XML file:

```
<products>
  <product_id value="1">
    <tab_id value="351">
        <city_name value="Jamnagar"/>
        <individual_sex value="2"/>
    </tab_id>
  </product_id>
  <product_id value="2">
    <tab_id value="352">
        <city_name value="Rajkot"/>
        <individual_sex value="2"/>
    </tab_id>
  </product_id>
</products>
```

This is my try in php XPath

```
list ($gender_id) = $product->xpath("//individual_sex[@value='$sex']/../../@value");
```

I'm try to check if the `individual_sex` attribute value is matching then return both `product_id` and `1, 2` (this is `product_id`).

Comment: What's your question? What have you tried? What's the error you have faced?

Comment: i just now edit my question add my xpath...

Comment: @fapDaddy nothing error its only return me first product_id

Comment: Your xpath works fine; It's your assignment (`list($gender_id)`) that's incorrect. Your xpath returns an array with two value, so you need to use something like `list($g1,$g2)=$xml->xpath(...)`.

Comment: @Passerby in this xml your suggestion is right but if unlimited product on xml then its not good work to write every time ($g1,$2,...,$n)

Comment: i have one JavaScript xpath this work fine. this is the xpath of javascript... `var xPath = '//*[local-name() = "individual_sex" and ' +
                            '(@value = '3')]' + 
                            '/../../@value';`

Comment: @jacklanza Then can you tell me what you expect `$gender_id` to be? If you want it to be an array you can simply use `$gender_id=$xml->xpath(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as already said by several users, your `xpath` is fine, but your use of `list`not correct here.
To access the individual values of `<product_id>`, do:

```
// assuming $xml is your simplexml-object...
$results = $xml->xpath("//individual_sex[@value='2']/../../@value");

foreach ($results as $result) echo $result['value'],"<br />";
```

live-demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/h0Ckxc

Answer (score 0):

You just made a little mistake in your code, you assign just one entry from all to the variable:

```
list ($gender_id) = ...
```

See http://php.net/list. If you want to obtain the whole array, assign it:

```
$gender_ids = ...
```

See as well http://php.net/array and the very basic descriptions about how to write code in PHP, its basic syntax.